# Increasing Maximum Upload File Size Limit on Wordpress and Raspberry Pi

Tags: wordpress, apache, raspberry-pi

so I'm hosting a Wordpress website on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ in my local area network LAN.
The site is working OK.

The problem is, I can't seem to change the "Maximum Upload File Size" if I wanted to upload an image or even an already built WP site that is 180MB and migrate it to the Raspberry Pi. Default is 2MB.

This is the tutorial I followed:
https://raspberrytips.com/wordpress-on-raspberry-pi/
I have researched online how to increase the maximum file size, and editing 4 files inside your WordPress project is what they recommend:

1. **.htaccess**  (located in the root directory)
2. **php.ini**  (located or create it in the root directory)
3. **wp-config.php**  (located in the root directory)
4. **functions.php**  (located wp-content/themes/astra)

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE ON EACH ONE OF THOSE FILES (I have tried with 256MB and 64MB):

**.htaccess**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**wp-config.php**

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize', '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M' );
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '64M' );
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
@ini_set( 'max_input_time', '300' );
```

**php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

**functions.php**

```
 @ini_set( 'upload_max_size', '64M' );
 @ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M' );
 @ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

I ran the following commands after that:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service mysql restart
```

Gave the server 5 minutes just in case since I've read it can take a while for changes...but the 2MB remained the same.
I tried a plugin called:

[image]

I went to that plugin and set the maximum to 256MB and it changed the value....but when I tried uploading the 180MB already built site I want to migrate it gives me an error....but is accepts the upload and the progress bar reaches 100% but with an error.

This also happens with an image over 2MB even though the max upload file size was changed from 2MB to 256MB.
Any help will do...thanks.

Comment: did you check which `php.ini` is being used in the server? `php --ini` you can use this command to know the information. maybe it's a different file then you modified.

Comment: Make sure you edit the right php.ini file. Lots of Ubuntu installations have more than one. Say `sudo find / -type f -name php.ini -ls` to a shell to find them all.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this for the last couple days. This is what finally fixed it for me. Oh and btw, I am hosting in Ubuntu server 20.04. And my limits are big, so adjust yours to fit your situation.

According to php dot net:

post_max_size must be larger than upload_max_filesize, and memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size

```
upload_max_filesize = 900M
post_max_size = 901M
memory_limit = 902M
```

Next I had to find the php.ini file that was in use. My WordPress was using 7.4 for some odd reason. And there are multiple versions on there.

```
locate apache2/php.ini

    /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
    /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
    /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
    /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
```

I modified the 7.4 file with the above limits (around 900M):

```
vi /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

And restarted apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

The changes were effective immediately and I could finally upload larger files!

[image: wordpress maximum upload file size]